# Looking for URL to File synchronization tool

Tags: file-synchronization

I'm looking for a utility that will automatically synchronize a file available via a URL ie:

```
www.someurl.com/file.txt
```

to a local location on a computer ie:

```
c:\files\file.txt
```

It needs to download a copy of the URL file and overwrite the existing file on either a schedule, or based on file changes. (not appending, not making a new file with a different extension, etc).

I've been digging around google for about half an hour and am not having any luck finding something that does that, but I know it has to be out there.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how automatically - in other words should it constantly monitor or just run at x interval or ?

Comment: Instantaneous is not required - something where I could set an interval to check the source file would be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to retrieve the file:

- free and open-source
- works on Linux and Windows

You can use [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) on Linux or Windows Task Scheduler on Windows to schedule your synchronization. Both are free.

---

Edit: to deploy you can:

- on Windows use the [command line scheduler "at"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/396099/395857): e.g. `at 8am /EVERY:M,T,W,Th,F,S,Su cmd /c c:\myapp.exe`
- on Linux use [crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/878600/395857): `(crontab -l ; echo "0 * * * * your_command") | sort - | uniq - | crontab -`

Comment: This solution would work and if there is nothing more suited I will use it, but I have to roll this out to six or seven computers so an all in one single application would be preferred if available.  Once I get this account up to 15 I'll throw an upvote your way, and a solution if nobody else comes up with something simpler.

Comment: Deploy commands added to answer.